# Bulma's navbar-buger doesnt connect to menu items in Vue.js 2

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bulma

I am trying to implement a navbar for my application whose front end is built using Vue 2.0 and Bulma . It works well on desktops and but on smaller screens its showing the burger icon but it is not showing any elements. Its just present.

```
<template>
<div class="container is-fluid">
    <div>
      <nav class="navbar is-dark">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#">
              <img  alt="K R O N O S" height="100px">
          </a>
          <div class="button navbar-burger" data-target="navMenu">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-menu" id="navMenu">
          <div class="navbar-end">
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <a class="" href="#"> Docs </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-item ">
              <a class="" href="#"> Report </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <a class="">More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <a class="">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
  var $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0)
  // Check if there are any navbar burgers
  if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {
    // Add a click event on each of them
    $navbarBurgers.forEach(function ($el) {
      $el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
        var target = $el.dataset.target
        var $target = document.getElementById(target)

        // Toggle the class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
        $el.classList.toggle('is-active')
        $target.classList.toggle('is-active')
      })
    })
  }
})
export default {
  name: 'Navbar',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
div{
  border: 0px solid black;
}
</style>
```

As you can see I have tried implementing the example code in on which was present here but with no use. Shouldnt Bulma give me responsive navbar out of the box. All the examples and solutions I have found are for the older "nav" class not the newer "navbar". Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Vue why do you define events using plain JS?

Comment: This was my testbed. I am new to Vue so didn't go ahead with it. Is there a more idiomatic vue way?

Comment: of course, vue makes it much easier to do these things, i suggest you read a bit about it

Comment: @fatman any pointers specifically?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: so basically if I'd bind the v-on:click directive to the navbar-burger and the callback function should change the value. That will work?

Comment: not exactly you need to also bind some data like: showNav or something like that to make the navigation show/hide. I really suggest you learn vue deeper, it will make your life much easier in the long run

Answer (score 7):

So, after a bit of studying the Vue guide and clues from [fatman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812303/fatman)'s comments, this is the fix I applied.

The above code works , but this is a more vue-ish way to do the navbar-burger menu.

```
<template>

      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand is-large">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="#">
              <img  alt="K R O N O S" height="100px">
          </a>
          <button @click="makeBurger" class="button navbar-burger" data-target="navMenu" v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': activator }">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-menu" id="navMenu" v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': activator }">
          <div class="navbar-end">
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <a class="" href="#"> Docs </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-item ">
              <a class="" href="#"> Report </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <a class="">More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <a class="">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Navbar',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: '',
      activator: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    makeBurger () {
      this.activator = !this.activator
      return this.activator
    }
  }
}
</script>
<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
div{
  border: 0px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Hope this helps someone. The show/hide functionality is taken care by Bulma.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but

1. will not close the menu
2. will cause router-links not to work

For 1.) I recommend adding @click to navbar-item as well:

```
<a @click="makeBurger" class="navbar-item">
    <router-link to="/login">
        {{link1}}
    </router-link>
</a>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on point 1. Cuz I am able to close my menu

Comment: Hi @VipinRai,
with the code at navbar-item the menu closes, otherwise not. But with 2.) I have been unprecise: the user has to click the text of the navbar-item explicitly, not the row - then the content of the router will be loaded. If the user clicks the row - the menu disappears, but the content stays the same.